# When to use setup() hook of Vue Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

As the [composition api](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/) of Vue has ported for the [current version, v2](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api), apparently we can start to use it before the release of the new version.

The examples generally feature a newly introduced `setup()` hook, and it is depicted [alone](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/#api-introduction) and or along with basic [JS functions](https://gist.github.com/yyx990803/8854f8f6a97631576c14b63c8acd8f2e).

At first glance I thought it is simply a place for initializing **reactive** data and I'd ask sth like: *in what cases should it be used*.

However, when you dig more, it looks as if composition API cannot be implemented without it. So, what is the thing with that hook and can it be used with `data`, `methods`, `computed` etc. fields outside it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The composition API is really another way to do the same thing as before. Mainly:

- The local state in `data` is replaced by a call to `reactive`.
- Hooks `mounted`, `beforeDestroy`, etc. are replaced by subscriptions to `onMounted`, `onUnmounted` etc.
- Declarations in `watch` are replaced by calls to `watch`.
- `computed` properties are replaced by a call to `computed` in an object passed to `reactive`.
- The `setup` function returns an object that contains a composition of all the things that have to remain accessible from outside the setup function, in particular from the template. And this feature replaces old `methods`.

> I'd ask sth like: *in what cases should it be used*.

Nothing is deprecated, so you have now two ways to do the same thing and nothing prevents you from mixing if you want. Nothing except the composition API is better than the old way. And once you adopt it, you will completely abandon the old way of doing things.

See also: [The motivation of the Vue's creator](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/issues/55#issuecomment-504875870).

Comment: I don't really feel like this answered "when to use it".

Comment: I came here because I didn't really understand the reasoning behind the changes with Vue 3. You really helped me there, also with the link to the explanation of the creator of Vue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the componsition API is implemented with the `setup()` method. The usage of `setup` tells Vue that you want to use the functional approach of the composition API to implement the component.

> The Composition API is a set of additive, function-based APIs that
>   allow flexible composition of component logic.

**example:** how to implement `data` `methods` and `computed` in this functional approach

```
<template>
  <button @click="increment">
    Count is: {{ state.count }}, double is: {{ state.double }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      count: 0,
      double: computed(() => state.count * 2)
    })

    function increment() {
      state.count++
    }

    return {
      state,
      increment
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Note: the composition API is also available with Vue.js 2 as plugin (See for more details: https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/)

Comment: Well, your note is not true: composition api is available in V2 too, as I have mentioned. See also [demos](https://github.com/LinusBorg/composition-api-demos) by LinusBorg. Apart from that, may I ask for addition in your answer that good-old `data`, `methods` etc and composition api are mutually exclusive?

Comment: @vahdet, thanks I have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

### I know this is an old post but just placing this here for future visitors like myself:

The composition API is meant to solve the issue of maintainability and scalability by allowing you to reuse and share data and logic between components. This way you don't have to repeat the same logic in different components.

The composition API allows you to write all the logic in a separate "composable" function and import and use it in the `setup()` hook. You can still have reactive data properties, methods, lifecycle hooks, computed props, etc. in this composable function, but you have to import it from 'vue' and implement it a little differently.

**Note:** If you want to, you can still use the default data object, methods, lifecycle hooks, etc. in the component like normal, in addition to the `setup()` hook. Even if you're already using the same things in that `setup()` hook.

You could also just write all the logic inside the `setup()` hook, inside the component, as opposed to having it in a separate composable function and importing it, but that defeats the purpose of reusing logic between components. The upside with this is that you can write your own abstraction (as You says), be more functional orientated, and follow a React(hooks)-like structure, which could be preferable for people coming from React.

It's not necessarily better. It loses the structure, readability and aesthetics you get with using the options API (old way). Both have their use cases. It depends on what the goals and needs are for your project and team. I personally prefer the options API, but I would most definitely reach for the composition API when I need to reuse the logic in another component.

Here's a good tutorial that highlights some of the differences: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hYYGbV60Vq3IXYNfDk8At1